# Laravel auth in custom fields

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I have an existing laravel project, where i create role base authentication like (user & admin) and this table relation with multiple table where relation make with id (primary key). Now i want to change primary key from id to user_id.

```
protected $primaryKey = "user_id";
```

It's call in User model. User table's changed id to user_id. But after change this, i have face many problem because of relational database with others table. How can i solve this problem without any change of migration table?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to change primary key from `id` to `user_id` ?

Comment: this project merge with another project where primary key use as user_id. So i want to change and all data access from this table

Comment: I think you should add a column for `user_id` and generate `user_id` value base on `id` column. So you can keep current relationship and also work fine with another project as you told